# AWS EB CLI Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I have successfully managed to deploy my Django project on AWS EB using EB CLI through PyCharm terminal local project on a Windows PC, however I would like to access the project via an EB instance on AWS console to edit some files individually instead of deploying the whole project each time.

The instance is Amazon Linux 2.

I connected to the EC2 instance of my project environment on the AWS EC2 instance connect and brings up the Elastic Beanstalk EC2 message, however I'm unable to find my project files within this console. Is there a way to access my already deployed project with AWS console, and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't see your files from the AWS console. Your files were deployed to a virtual machine of which filesystem can be viewed if you connect to the instance.

The recommended way to connect to an Elastic Beanstalk instance is to use [`eb ssh`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html). This will expose port 22 temporarily on the instance and will allow you to safely connect to it.

`eb ssh` requires an SSH client to be installed, nowadays even Windows machines do come with SSH pre-installed, so this should not be a problem. It also requires to have an SSH key pair, which can be generated by running `eb init --interactive` and selecting yes when it asks for creating a key pair.